# A Java theading program which reads lines of a huge CSV file

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a huge CSV file with over 700K + lines. I have to parse lines of that CSV file and do operations. I thought of doing it by using threading. What I attempt to do at the first is simple. Every thread should process unique lines of the CSV file. I have a limited number of lines to read to 3000 only. I create three threads. Each thread should read a line of the CSV file. Following is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

class CSVOps implements Runnable
{
    static int lineCount = 1;
    static int limit = 3000;
    BufferedReader CSVBufferedReader;

    public CSVOps(){} // Default constructor

    public CSVOps(BufferedReader br){
        this.CSVBufferedReader = br;
    }

    private synchronized void readCSV(){
        System.out.println("Current thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        String line;
        try {
            while((line = CSVBufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                lineCount ++;
                if(lineCount >= limit){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        readCSV();
    }

}

class CSVResourceHandler
{
    String CSVPath;

    public CSVResourceHandler(){ }// default constructor

    public CSVResourceHandler(String path){
        File f = new File(path);
        if(f.exists()){
            CSVPath = path;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong file path! You gave: "+path);
        }
    }

    public BufferedReader getCSVFileHandler(){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
            FileReader is = new FileReader(CSVPath);
            br = new BufferedReader(is);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        return br;
    }
}

public class invalidRefererCheck
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        String pathToCSV = "/home/shantanu/DEV_DOCS/Contextual_Work/invalid_domain_kw_site_wise_click_rev2.csv";
        CSVResourceHandler csvResHandler = new CSVResourceHandler(pathToCSV);
        CSVOps ops = new CSVOps(csvResHandler.getCSVFileHandler());

        Thread t1 = new Thread(ops);
        t1.setName("T1");

        Thread t2 = new Thread(ops);
        t1.setName("T2");

        Thread t3 = new Thread(ops);
        t1.setName("T3");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

Class CSVResourceHandler simple finds if the passed file exists and then creates a BufferedReader and gives it. This reader is passed to the CSVOps class. It has a method, readCSV, which reads a single line of the CSV file and prints it. There is a limit set to 3000.

Now for threads to not mess up with count, I declare those limit and count variable both as static. When I run this program I get weird output. I get only about 1000 records, and sometimes I get 1500. They are in random order. At the end of output I get two lines of the CSV file and the current thread name comes out to be main!!

I am very much a novice with threads. I want reading this CSV file to become fast. What can it be done?

Comment: Using more than one reading thread won't help. The blocking point isn't the CPU but IO.

Comment: I would suggest you get working with one thread and pass each line as you read it to a queue which can be consumed by a second thread. This ensures that order is preserved.

Comment: @dystroy: but then in such case, what can be done?

Comment: Can anyone explain me why only output of any one of the thread is visible? I have set limit of 3000 lines, what I get it about 1000 lines everytime

Comment: use something faster than Java, that's constructed exactly for extraction and processing reports :D? (psst.. it's Perl)

Comment: Use only one thread for reading. Profile to see what's long. But the slowest operation here is probably the System.out.println.

Comment: It is hard to speed up the IO using multiple threads, however breaking a file into lines of String can be surprisingly expensive and using a seperate thread to do this can be useful.

Comment: `why only output of any one of the thread is visible?` you have a bug in your code.

Comment: @hovanessyan Perl's famous "speed up HDD by 50% command" was finally implemented? Because otherwise you'll hardly see a speedup in an IO limited program, independent of the language. That said: Memory map the file, use one reader (split up lines) and probably one consumer (csv parsing is trivial, I doubt that'll give much improvement over the single threaded solution though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading the file in big chunks. Allocate a big buffer object, read a chunk, parse back from the end to find the last EOL char, copy the last bit of the buffer into a temp string, shove a null into the buffer at the EOL+1, queue off the buffer reference, immediately create a new one, copy in the temp string first, then fill up the rest of the buffer and repeat until EOF.  Repeat until done.  Use a pool of threads to parse/process the buffers.

You have to queue up whole chunks of valid lines.  Queueing off single lines will result in the thread comms taking longer than the parsing.

Note that this, and similar, will probably result in the chunks being processed 'out-of-order' by the threads in the pool. If order must be preserved, (for example, the input file is sorted and the output is going into another file which must remain sorted), you can have the chunk-assembler thread insert a sequence-number in each chunk object.  The pool threads can then pass processed buffers to yet another thread, (or task), that keeps a list of out-of-order chunks until all previous chunks have come in.

Multithreading does not have to be difficult/dangerous/ineffective.  If you use queues/pools/tasks, avoid synchronize/join, don't continually create/terminate/destroy threads and only queue around large buffer objects that only one thread ever gets to work on at a time. You should see a good speedup with next-to-no possibility of deadlocks, false-sharing, etc.

The next step in such a speedup would be to pre-allocate a pool queue of buffers to eliminate continual creation/deletion of the buffers and associated GC and with a (L1 cache size) 'dead-zone' at the start of every buffer to eliminate cache-sharing completely.
That would go plenty quick on a multicore box, (esp. with an SSD!).

Oh, Java, right. I apologise for the 'CplusPlus-iness' of my answer with the null terminator.  The rest of the points are OK, though.  This should be a language-agnostic answer:)

Comment: thanks for an answer in great details. `This should be a language-agnostic answer`. Yes I will remember that and see if I can fit that in java :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first, ***do not use*** multiple threads to do parallel I/O from a single mechanical disk. It actually slows down performance because the mechanical head needs to seek the next reading location every time a thread gets a chance to run. Thus you are unnecessarily bouncing the disk's head around which is a costly operation.

Use a single producer multiple consumer model to read lines using a single thread and process them using a pool of workers.

On to your problem:

Shouldn't you actually be waiting for the threads to finish before exiting main?

```
public class invalidRefererCheck
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        ...
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: By default java thread's aren't daemons, so no he doesn't have to.

Comment: `Use a single producer multiple consumer model to read lines using a single thread and process them using a pool of workers.`. Thanks for that clue, I was just onto it. And join() actually queues up the processing of one thread after another, so that won't halt the main till all threads finish, right? I mean in theory it was so :O

Comment: @Shades88: Actually no. After all the threads are started they run in parallel with the main thread and with each other. The `join` just guarantees that the main thread won't make progress until its children finish, but the children will still work in parallel with each other.